# UBuntu 18.04 on Xorg, multiple display nightmare

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Dell XPS 9550 on Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome (on Xorg).
I have it configured with the nvidia drivers v390 as below:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 960M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.87
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.87
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 390.87
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

It "works" but the issue is that the main screen on this laptop is 4K and I have connected 2 external monitors to it which have a max resolution of 1920x1080. If I zoom 200% on the 4K screen, the display is very comfortable but the zooming is also applying to the 2 other monitors making it far too big to do anything on them. If I set the zoom at 100%, the 2 external monitors display very well but then the 4K monitor font size and icons are far too small to even read.

I read a lot of material where people us xrandr but then it doesn't seem to apply with nvidia-drivers in the way...

Has anyone managed to configure something similar where I can use 2 or 3 monitors with an NVidia card on Xorg where one is 4K and the rest is normal resolution?

Of course there is another solution to use Wayland and this one does a very good scaling, but it doesn't work with the NVidia drivers (so falls back on the Intel card of the laptop) and a lot of applications do not work on Wayland.

Any help is appreciated ;o)

Thanks

Comment: Xorg doesn't support fractional scaling. You have to use Wayland instead of Xorg. Wayland is still buggy and you have to use Intel graphics.